# SQL in QlikView script - how to make better performance in a 'case' statement

Tags: sql, performance, qlikview, qliksense

It is possible to make better performance for below part of script?

```
case when recip = 'client' 
        then 
            cast(cast(cast(replace(replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),
            substring(replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),
            charindex('<Jv-Ins',
            replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),1),
                        charindex('<Claim',replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),1)-    charindex('<Jv-Ins',
            replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),1)),'<Jv-Ins>') as xml).query('data(/Jv-Ins/Claim/Contract/SharePercentage/Rate)') as varchar(6)) as float)
            
     when recip = 'reClient' 
        then 
            cast(cast(cast(replace(replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),
            substring(replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),
            charindex('<Jv-Ins',
            replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),1),
            charindex('<Claim',replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),1)-charindex('<Jv-Ins',
            replace(cast(x.MESSAGE_DATA as varchar(12)),'ac:','ac'),1)),'<Jv-Ins>') as xml).query('data(/Jv-Ins/Claim/Contract/SharePercentage/Rate)') as varchar(6)) as float)  end  [Percent Share],
```

This lines slows down reload, now it is over 2 hours. Without this lines script reload in 4 min.
This sql script is built-in in Qlikview script, so data is going thru connector.
I'm newbe in SQL, so I was thinking about store table in QVD and calculate this part in Qlikview script, but I think it doesn't make a sense for better performance.
Any ideas what can help for better performance?

Comment: Looks like a kind of xml mangling. You can benefit from using XML tools of your DBMS instead of string functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what's going on here but it looks like this script is conditionally parsing some XML stored as a string and then querying that to get a `[Rate]` value? Qlik let's you load XML *files* but I don't believe you can parse XML from string values that are already loaded.

***Note that my suggestions below are an attempt to make the most of your situation, the best course of action may just be to parse the XML before it's stored to the DB. Barring that, continue on...***

What you could do is just load the original field as-is:

```
-- SQL:
case
    when recip in ('client', 'reClient') then x.MESSAGE_DATA
    when recip = 'etc' then ...
end
```

(You probably wouldn't even need a `case` statement at that point but I don't know what the rest of your script looks like.)

Then just use basic Qlik string functions to get to your desired `[Rate]` value, something like this:

```
// Qlik load script:
Load 
    [XML String Full]
  , Num#(KeepChar(TextBetween([XML String Full], '<Rate>', '</Rate>'), '0123456789')) / 100 as [Percent Share]
Resident [Raw data from DB];
```

That script uses the [`TextBetween()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/TextBetween.htm) to get the value in the `<Rate>` XML node. Then it uses the [`KeepChar()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/KeepChar.htm) to make sure we only have numbers from it. The [`Num#()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterpretationFunctions/num_hash.htm) is then used to ensure we properly interpret this as a numerical value. Finally, we divide all of that by 100 to get an actual rate value (Assuming the value from the DB is something like **"4%"** rather than **0.04**; you can ditch the `/ 100` part if not).